# Nature of infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was doing some exercises on the nature of infinite series when I came across this one intriguing series - $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{\ln(i+1)}.$$ I tried to solve it with D'Alembert's ratio test and came at the solution that this series is convergent as $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}|$ comes out to be $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}|\frac{-\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+2)}| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+2)}$ which is smaller than 1 as $\ln x$ is strictly increasing. So, the $-$ sign doesn't really make any difference. But the answer in the textbook is that this series is conditionally convergent, meaning that it wouldn't have been convergent if not for the $-$ sign. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: What do you mean by  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1^{n-1})}{ln\enspace (i+1)}$ ?

Comment: The limit is not smaller than $1$. It's smaller or equal to $1$.

Comment: @Gae.S.  so is it convergent?

Comment: @Sil yes sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: What does the ratio test say ? If the limit is equal to one one might not be able to conclude anything.

Comment: The series is indeed conditionally convergent and not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan but isn't log a monotonically increasing function? So shouldn't it be a bit less than one?

Comment: @PrathamYadav but the limit is 1, read the ratio test carefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Actually, by D'Alembert's test, the ratio limit converges to 1 (just try applying L'Hôpital's). To see that it is not absolutely convergent, consider the series $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln{i+1}}$. Now, as $\ln(x)$ grows in a smaller rate than $x$, we have that for some big natural number $n_0$, if $i > n_0$, then $\ln{i+1} < i + 1$, which implies that $\frac{1}{\ln{i+1}}> \frac{1}{i}$ . Comparison to the harmonic series gives us the conclusion that $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln{i+1}} $ is divergent - which implies that, if convergent, the series in your question does it conditionally

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável Thank you for the prompt reply and the answer. I have understood my mistake now.

Comment: Concerning the value of this series it is $\;\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}1-\eta(x)\,dx\;$ with $\eta$ the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{\ln(i+1)}$ is not absolutely convergent, because $0<\ln(i+1)<i+1$, hence 
$$\frac1{\ln(i+1)} >\frac 1{i+1},$$
and the harmonic series diverges.

However it is conditionally convergent by Leibniz' test since $\;\dfrac1{\ln(i+1)}\;$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$.